# Why does the min function apparently add the name of the function to the output?

Tags: google-sheets, min, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a small table with usernames and dates in a Google Drive spreadsheet as part of some manual logging.
e.g.:

```
| User1 | 01/09/2019 |
| User1 | 09/09/2019 |
| User2 | 13/09/2019 |
| User1 | 05/10/2019 |
```

(dates are formatted DD/MM/YYYY)
I want to create an overview of when each username was first logged. For this I created a second table with below function for the first column:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A7)
```

For the second column, I wrote below function:

```
=QUERY(A2:B7, "SELECT MIN(B) WHERE A='"&C2&"'", 1)
```

The output I'm expecting to see is this:

```
| User1 | 01/09/2019 |
| User2 | 13/09/2019 |
```

But for some reason, the output I receive is this:

```
| User1 | min 01/09/2019 |
| User2 | 13/09/2019 |
```

What can I do to avoid the 'min' being added in the output? I don't see why this is being added in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single step with this formula:

```
=query(A:B,"select A, min(B) where A is not null group by A",1)
```

Also, I suspect your current date formatting is MM/dd/YYYY, and that's why "13/09/2019" isn't recognised as a date and creates weird behaviours.

Try to change the format (at least temporarily), using full months names, so you'll know for sure. If that's the case, just fix your dates and the formula above should do just fine:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By putting ,1) after the query, you're telling it that the data (starting in row 2) has a header. So it uses whatever it finds in row 2 (1/9/2019) and adds it to the default header (min). If you would like your original formula to work as expected, change

```
=QUERY(A2:B7, "SELECT MIN(B) WHERE A='"&C2&"'", 1)
```

to

```
=QUERY(A2:B7, "SELECT MIN(B) WHERE A='"&C2&"' label min(B) ''")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the min function apparently add the name of the function to the output?

**A:** because of that last `1` in your query formula.

---

instead, use this formula:

```
=QUERY(A1:B, 
 "select A,min(B) 
  where A is not null 
  group by A 
  label min(B)''", 0)
```

[image: 0]